# Hibernate Environment in JBoss

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I have two same copy of JBoss and same classpath entries and corresponding jars in the classpath which are resided in the same folder hierarchy on two servers.When I am starting up JBoss in one server it is showing

```
[Environment] Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
[Environment] hibernate.properties not found
[Environment] Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

and other one is showing

```
[Environment] Hibernate 3.1.1
[Environment] hibernate.properties not found
[Environment] using CGLIB reflection optimizer
```

Where to find out which hibernate and byte code provider is being used.This query is linked with my previous query I think this is the reason.Again I repeat both JBoss copies and jar files in the classpaths and .bash_profile copies are same.Is there anything that depends on the system ? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arka

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Look for folder `%JBOSS_HOME%/common/lib` and check Hibernate version used inside `hibernate-core.jar` (open `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file).

Both versions of jar files should be the same if the JBoss copies are the same.

Comment: Anyway, Hibernate 3.1.1 seems too old, so I'm sure JBoss versions used are not exactly the same: Hibernate 3.3.1.GA is included in JBoss 5.1.0.GA, and JBoss 4.0.5 uses Hibernate 3.2.0.GA...